# where to add new {target = "_blank"} in the link @Html.ActionLink ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to open the link in new page when click the link but where to add the code

```
new {target = "_blank"}
```

in this link ,

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Result", "MasterDetails", new { id = item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of the `htmlArguments`, after the route value. You don't necessarily put the whole thing in; you merge with other html arguments, such as `@class`:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Result", "MasterDetails", 
         new { id = item.LabOrders.ORDER_ID}, 
         new { @class = "btn btn-primary", target="_blank" })
</td>
```